what does the sentence highlighted in blue mean?
I can't quite understand what the sentence means, specially the もし. it doesn't seem to be conditional, so why is it there? 

もし by itself is not odd, and it is part of a conditional expression. もし is a guiding adverb that pairs with なら.

もし～と思ったのなら
If you thought ～, then...

That said, your sentence is grammatically wrong for a different reason. What's really wrong with your sentence is "冒頭の学習者の質問や". It says や, but there is no other noun in the "list", and there is no corresponding verb for this, either.
To fix this, you can simply remove the "冒頭の学習者の質問や" part:

もし例文の違いは何？なぜ「なければならない」を使ったほうがいいの？と思ったのなら、ぜひこの記事を読んでみてください。
If you thought "What's the difference between the two example sentences?" or "Why is it better to use なければならない?", then try reading this article.

Alternatively, we can keep 冒頭の学習者の質問 and supply some corresponding verb for it, like this:

もし冒頭の学習者の質問が気になるか、例文の違いは何？なぜ「なければならない」を使ったほうがいいの？と思ったのなら、ぜひこの記事を読んでみてください。
If you're curious about the question of the learner at the beginning, or if you thought "What's the difference between the two example sentences?" or "Why is it better to use なければならない?", then try reading this article.


Parts of it are quotes; I've put quotation marks (「」 and 『』) to help visualize:
もし冒頭の学習者の質問や、「例文の違いは何？」、「なぜ『なければならない』を使ったほうがいいの？」と思ったのなら、ぜひこの記事を読んでみてください。
The もし - なら here is the "if - then" clause.
